# Prevent HttpHandler from handling WCF requests

Tags: wcf, httphandler

I have a web site that hosts a WCF service and an HttpHandler.  When I turn on aspNetCompatibilityEnabled the HttpHandler starts picking up my WCF requests.  I would not think this could happen because it has a .svc extention and the handlers are not configured to handle .svc files.  The handler is registered as so:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="TTPDeploy" path="*.deploy" verb="*" type="ServiceHost.DeploymentHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="TTPManifest" path="*.manifest" verb="*" type="ServiceHost.DeploymentHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="TTPApplication" path="*.application" verb="*" type="ServiceHost.DeploymentHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm sure this is simply because I don't understand something about WCF and HttpHandlers.  Thoughts?

---

## Update

I ended up solving the problem in a different way.  Because I couldn't get my WCF requests to work while having aspNetCompatibilityEnabled set to true, I reverted it back to false.

My core problem was that I needed to get the physical file path to my web from with a WCF call.  I found another post (which I'm unable to find now) that stated when using WCF to get the physical application path, you should use `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`.  This is a much more straight forward approach to the problem, but still doesn't answer this question.

**Why does my handler pick up my WCF requests when it's not registered to .svc files?**

Comment: Self-host your WCF service in a Windows app/NT Service - you'll have none of those issues......

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option as I need the flexibility/configurability that IIS gives me out of the box (albeit, some trouble associated with that flexibility).

Comment: What flexibility is there that you don't have when self-hosting??

Comment: If you're speaking only of WCF, then there's not much argument I can make, but I also need to handle other web requests from a ClickOnce application that as far as I can tell will need to be IIS hosted. The click-once will use this web site as it's source for updates, and the HttpHandler will be used to receive and respond to these requests. Since I already have to use IIS for that, I might as well host my WCF service there too to avoid having to install a windows service as well.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is picking up the request due to some config, could be in machine.config.

To allow the request to get to your handler, add the following to your web.config file:

```
<compilation>     
 <buildProviders>         
  <remove extension=".svc" />     
 </buildProviders> 
</compilation>
```

Comment: No, nothing in the machine.config.  I still need the web site to respond to WCF requests so removing the .svc extention from the build providers would be a bad idea, correct?  Essentially, I want both my WCF and handlers to respond to requests.

Comment: I do not think that two handlers can handle the same request. Once one handler picks up the request it is no longer available for other handlers.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm not trying to handle one file with two handlers.  I'm trying to handle two different file types (i.e. .application and .svc) with two different handlers.